# Convert the class as data table using extension method and lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to create a extension method to export the class as data-table, in this method I want to give facility to user to export the property with different name in datatable, suppose property name in class is "LoginName" but user want to export it as "Login" in data-table, also user can specify multiple properties to rename.

for example following is the class

```
public class UserInfo
{
   public int UserID { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string LoginName { get; set; }
   public int CompanyID { get; set; }
}
```

to export this class as data-table user will use extension method like this

```
UserInfo us = UserRep.GetUser("userID","Pass");
DataTable userDetails = null;

//Follwing is a pseudo code it could be different in possible manner
userDetails = us.ExportAsDataTable(u=> new {{u.LoginName,"Login"}, {u.CompanyID ,"Company"}});

//Or

 userDetails = us.ExportAsDataTable(u=> new { Login = u.LoginName, Company = u.CompanyID});
```

following ExportAsDataTable metod I have created to do the functionality but unable to give correct expression to take the user input.

```
public static DataTable ExportAsDataTable<TSource, TProperty>(this TSource instance, Expression<Func<TSource, KeyValuePair<TProperty, string>>> renamePropertyMap)
{
   DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

   //Doing export stuff here

   return dataTable;
 }
```

//Or

```
public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(this T instance, Expression<Func<T, object>> renamePropertyMap) where T : EntityBase
{
  //Using this method I am able to get the new name of column from expression like this but not getting the original property name 

   string columnName = (renamePropertyMap.Body as NewExpression).Members[0].Name   

   /*note :- result in columnName is "Login" which is fine,
             but I need to get orignal property name as well, that is
             "LoginName", I am unable to get it from expression.*/


   DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
   //Doing export stuff here

   return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you ExportAs method only supports 1 property?

Comment: You can access original property name as: `((renamePropertyMap.Body as NewExpression).Arguments[j1] as MemberExpression).Member.Name`

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this instead:

```
public class FluentBuilder<T>
{
    private readonly T _input;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public FluentBuilder(T input)
    {
        _input = input;
    }
    public FluentBuilder<T> Map(Expression<Func<T, object>> selector, string name)
    {
        MemberExpression member = selector.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (member == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Expression '{0}' refers to a method, not a property.", selector));

        var propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (propInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Expression '{0}' refers to a field, not a property.", selector));

        _mappings.Add(propInfo.Name, name);
        return this;
    }

    private string GetName(PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        string map;
        if (_mappings.TryGetValue(prop.Name, out map))
            return map;
        return prop.Name;
    }

    public DataTable ToDataTable(string tableName = null)
    {
        var result = new DataTable(tableName);
        foreach (var prop in _input.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            result.Columns.Add(GetName(prop));
        }

        var values = _input.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetMethod.Invoke(_input, new object[0])).ToArray();
        result.Rows.Add(values);
        return result;
    }
}

public static class FluentBuilderExtensions
{
    public static FluentBuilder<T> SetupWith<T>(this T input)
    {
        return new FluentBuilder<T>(input);
    }
}

class Program
{
    public class UserInfo
    {
        public string MailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var userInfo = new UserInfo()
                       {
                           MailAddress = "foo@bar.com",
                           Username = "foouser",
                           Password = "barpassword"
                       };

        var dt = userInfo.SetupWith()
                         .Map(x => x.MailAddress, "address")
                         .Map(x => x.Username, "user")
                         .ToDataTable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not handle fields as well as properties?

Comment: Sorry, no particular reason. Just don't felt like it.

Comment: thanks @eocron, This solution work for me, but  I am thinking for one more approach if that prossible like MoreLINQ provides, I have update my original question and added //Or approach can you suggest me on that?.

Answer (score 1):

[MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) already provides [ToDatatable()](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/ToDataTable.cs) to convert an IEnumerable result to a DataTable. The method is available as part of the [full NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) or as a  [source package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.ToDataTable/) that you can add to your project.

To generate a DataTable from a subset of UserInfo properties, use a `Select` before calling `ToDataTable()`, eg :

```
var table = myUserInfos.Select(us=>new {Login=us.LoginName, Company=us.CompanyID})
                       .ToDataTable();
```

If you only have *one* item and want to convert it to a single-row DataTable:

- That's a *very* strange request. Why do you want to do that instead of eg binding the single object to the UI controls?
- You can wrap it in an array eg:

  ```
  var table = new[]{theUser}.Select(us=>new {Login=us.LoginName, Company=us.CompanyID})
                            .ToDataTable();
  ```

Comment: How does that help rename the properties to different column names as part of the conversion?

Comment: That's what Select does.

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean, but you're example also deletes every other property that should pass through, which you probably don't want to list by hand.

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, the above code in only to illustrate the requirement, actually I am migrating  my old asp.net web form application is mvc, in new MVC architecture my Data layer will still remain same from here I am passing datatable to stored procedure as parameters UDT (User Define table), hence I required to convert the class as datatable.

Answer (score 0):

I used `DataAnnotations` and `Reflection`.

You need to add reference of missing libraries from following. I tested this code and it is working.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var user = new UserInfo();

        var name = GetAttributeFrom<DisplayAttribute>(user, "LoginName").Name;

        var dt = objToDataTable(user);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static DataTable objToDataTable(UserInfo obj)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        UserInfo objU = new UserInfo();

        foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(UserInfo).GetProperties())
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(GetAttributeFrom<DisplayAttribute>(objU, info.Name).Name);
        }

        dt.AcceptChanges();

        return dt;
    }

    public static T GetAttributeFrom<T>(object instance, string propertyName) where T : Attribute
    {
        var attrType = typeof(T);
        var property = instance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        return (T)property.GetCustomAttributes(attrType, false).First();
    }

}


public class UserInfo
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "FName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "LName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Login")]
    public string LoginName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should default to using the Property name if the attribute is missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I build the extension method to convert the class as datatable

```
public static class EntityExtensions
{
    private static readonly string expressionCannotBeNullMessage = "The expression cannot be null.";
    private static readonly string invalidExpressionMessage = "Invalid expression.";

    public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(this T instance, Expression<Func<T, object>> proprtiesToSkip = null, Expression<Func<T, object>> proprtiesToRename = null) where T : EntityBase
    {
        string columnName = "";
        string orgPropName;
        int counter = 0;
        Dictionary<string, string> renameProperties = null;
        MemberInfo newName = null;
        NewExpression expression = null;
        List<string> skipProps = null;

    try
    {
        if (proprtiesToSkip != null )
        {
            if (proprtiesToSkip.Body is NewExpression)
            {
                skipProps = new List<string>();
                expression = (proprtiesToSkip.Body as NewExpression);
                foreach (var cExpression in expression.Arguments)
                {
                    skipProps.Add(GetMemberName(cExpression));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid expression supplied in proprtiesToSkip while converting class to datatable");
            }
        }

        if (proprtiesToRename != null)
        {
            if (proprtiesToRename.Body is NewExpression)
            {
                renameProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                expression = (proprtiesToRename.Body as NewExpression);
                foreach (var cExpression in expression.Arguments)
                {
                    newName = expression.Members[counter];
                    orgPropName = GetMemberName(cExpression);
                    renameProperties.Add(orgPropName, newName.Name);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid expression supplied in proprtiesToRename while converting class to datatable");
            }
        }

        var properties = instance.GetType().GetProperties().Where(o =>
        {
            return (skipProps != null && !skipProps.Contains(o.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                    (o.PropertyType != typeof(System.Data.DataTable) && o.PropertyType != typeof(System.Data.DataSet)));

        }).ToArray();


        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in properties)
        {
            columnName = "";
            if (renameProperties != null && renameProperties.ContainsKey(info.Name))
            {
                columnName = renameProperties[info.Name];
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnName))
            {
                columnName = info.Name;
            }

            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(columnName, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(info.PropertyType) ?? info.PropertyType));
        }

        object[] values = new object[properties.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(instance);
        }

        dataTable.Rows.Add(values);

        return dataTable;
    }
    finally
    {
        renameProperties = null;
        newName = null;
        expression = null;
        skipProps = null;
    }

}        
private static string GetMemberName(Expression expression)
{
    if (expression == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(expressionCannotBeNullMessage);
    }

    if (expression is MemberExpression)
    {
        // Reference type property or field
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression;
        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }

    throw new ArgumentException(invalidExpressionMessage);
}

}
```

Calling it like this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        CancelReason ad = new CancelReason();
        ad.BusinessLineID = 1;
        ad.CancelReasonCodeID = 2;
        ad.CancelRefund = "C";
        ad.CompanyID = 0;
        ad.DBOperation = 1;
        ad.Description = "test";
        ad.IsActive = "Y";
        ad.ReasonCode = "TestCode";
        ad.UpdateStamp = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        DataTable dt = ad.ConvertToDataTable(s => new { s.DBOperation, s.BusinessLineID, s.LoggedInUser }, r => new { Refund = r.CancelRefund, Company = r.CompanyID });

    }
}
```